# Find the minimal irreducible polynomial $Irr(a, \mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \leq \mathbb{C}$ and $a=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{8}}$. I have to find the minimal irreducible polynomial $Irr(a, \mathbb{Q})$.

$a$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^8-1=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$.

$x^4-1$ is not irreducible, since $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)$.

So, we have to determine if the polynomial $x^4+1$ is irreducible, right??

How could I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

Suppose $x^4 + 1$ is reducible. Then it is the product of two polynomials of smaller degree. The possibilities for these degrees are $1$, $3$ or $2$, $2$. Show that $x^4 + 1$ cannot have a rational root, and deduce that the case $1$, $3$ is not possible. Can $a$ be the root of a quadratic over the rationals?

Alternatively, apply the Eisenstein criterion to $(x+1)^4 + 1$.

Comment: I tried the second way and I got the following: $$f_1(x)=x^4+1 \Rightarrow f_1(x+1)=(x+1)^4+1=x^4+3x^3+6x^2+3x+2$$ Is it correct?? Can we apply the Eisenstein criterion in this case?? There is no prime that divides $2,3,6$, right?? 
$$$$
So, we have to show it with the first way, right??

Comment: @MaryStar ${4\choose 1}={4\choose 3}=4$

Comment: @user26857 Yes, you're right! So, we apply the Eisestein criterion with $p=2$, right??

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much!!! :-)